# Create a collection from background Tasks

Tags: c#, task

I have a C# web service in where I have a method called "async GetUser(string userid)".
In one of my methods I have a collection of userids.
What I want to do is something like this :

```
ICollection<User> users = /* Run GetUser(userid) for each userid concurrently*/
```

In other languages I am used to, like Go, what I would do is to run all "funcs" in the background and have each of of them to push to channel and simply collect the data until all the background jobs are completed.

Whats the right way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ICollection<User> users = await Task.WhenAll(userids.Select(GetUser));
```

`Select` runs `GetUser` for each id and returns a `Task<User>`.

`Task.WhenAll` waits for all the tasks to complete, and `await` unwraps the results into an array.